# Non-surjective linear operator that is open?

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, open-map

Is there any non-surjective linear operator that is open?

By the open mapping theorem, $T:X \to Y$ is open iff $T$ is surjective. Is it possible then to have a non-surjective linear operator that is open?

I have been thinking of $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2,\ (x, y) \to (x, 0)$

Here T is not surjective but the set $A = {(x, 0) \in \mathbb{R}^2} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is closed:
Let $(z^{(n)})_n \subset A,\ z^{(n)} = (x_n, y_n)$ be some sequence with $\lim x_n = x$. Then the sequence converges in $A$, and therefore $A$ is closed. So this wouldnt work as an example.

Comment: You need more hypotheses for us to understand.  What are $X,Y$?  Normed spaces?  Banach spaces (to apply the open mapping theorm)?  Topological vector spaces?  Is $T$ required to be linear?  To be continuous?

Comment: I am assuming the assumptions to apply the open mapping theorem are satisfied @GEdgar

Answer (score 3):

No such $T$ exists. $X$, of course, is open in $X$, so if $T$ is open then $T(X)$ must be open in $Y$. But $T(X)$ is a linear subspace of $Y$. If $T$ is not surjective, then $T(X)$ is a proper linear subspace, and one may see that a proper linear subspace can never be open.

Comment: Thanks, perfectly explained! I also would like to look at it from the logical point of view...
P = T is surjective.
Q = T is open.
We have $P \Leftrightarrow Q$, so $P \Rightarrow Q$ and $Q \Rightarrow P$.
However, if P is false and Q is either true or false, then $P \Rightarrow Q$ is true. 
P could be false (T is not surjective) and the implication still holds, that is Q is true (T is open)

Comment: @juan19.99 I’m not sure I follow. The question you asked is the contrapositive of, and therefore equivalent to, $Q \Rightarrow P$ in your notations. Why are you talking about $P \Rightarrow Q$?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. You are right. If T is surjective then it is open - If T is not open then it is not surjective

Answer (score 2):

If the range of $T$  is open it contains an open ball centered at $0.$ By the homogeneity the range is equal to the whole space.

The operator does not need  to be additive neither bounded, just homogeneous. Observe that homogeneity implies $T0=0$ and that has been used in the first sentence.